# Integral: $I=\int\limits_{1}^{e}\dfrac{\ln x+\sqrt{1+\ln x}}{x\sqrt{1+\ln x}}dx$

Tags: calculus

Evaluate: $\displaystyle I=\int\limits_{1}^{e}\dfrac{\ln x+\sqrt{1+\ln x}}{x\sqrt{1+\ln x}}dx$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint**: Substitue $u = 1 + \ln x$.